# Java - compilation error debug

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have a compilation error that I can't seem to fix. It gives me the message that it is a type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to List.
Below I have added the methods that it says the error is in.

```
// Read books from file
    public void readBooksFromFile() {
        if(booksDatabase != null && !booksDatabase.isEmpty()) {
            try (ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(booksDatabase))) {
                Books = input.readObject(); // Error here
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();                
            }
        }
    }
```

The second method

```
public ListBook(String booksDatabase) {
        this.booksDatabase = booksDatabase;
        readBooksFromFile(); // Error here
    }
```

The third method

```
public static void main (String[] args){
        // creates ListBook object to keep track of books in the library
        ListBook lb = new ListBook("books.dat"); // Error here

        // add books to the ListBook object
        lb.addBook(new Book("E-commerce", "Kenneth Laudon", "2014", "024449"));
        lb.addBook(new Book("Java Programming", "Daniel Liang", "2014", "761312"));
        lb.addBook(new Book("EU Internet Law", "Andrej Savin", "2015", "429379"));


         //New object
         //getter setter methods
         LibrarianMenu li = new LibrarianMenu(lb);
         //execute the function from the librarian.java
     }
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Confusing code to read.  You don't follow the Java coding standards.  What is Books?  It'd be better if you posted the entire class rather than method snippets.  We can't see the whole context.

Comment: Is Books a variable? if it is it needs to start with a lower case.Did you try to cast it: ClassName Books = (Classname)input.readObject();

Comment: You need to cast your ObjectInputStream--> (ListBook)ObjectInputStream

Comment: You should add casting to List type:

Answer (score 1):

ObjectInputStream returns an Object; you're obviously assigning it to Books, which is of type List.  Bad idea.

Worse, I think you're imagining that readObject can iterate over a collection and read multiple books into a List.  I think you should write that method so it reads a single Book and iterate over a collection, adding individual books to the list.

Answer (score 0):

When you obtain `mismatch: cannot convert from Object to List.` exception it means you are doing a illegal operation with types. That means you should cast your `input` object to the same type of `Books`.